# AWS API Gateway issue for HTTP Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I created an AWS API-gateway for an HTTP method `PUT`. When I do a test in API-gateway, that works fine, but when I call it from a REST client, I get `404 bad-request` and `missing authentication token` errors. I didn't set any authorization to `true` or a required API key to `true`.

I passed these query parameters to a REST client:

```
auth_id : 8798iuyiu123123
time_stamp :1231231
test_json : [{"id"=>"1","value"=>"mount"},{"id"=>"2","value"=>"chart"}]

HEADER
content-type : application/json
```

When I change the `test_json` value to `%5B%7B%22id%22:%221%22,%22value%22:%22test%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%222%22,%22value%22:%2213+%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%`, then I get the response.

i am new to react, calling from react

```
Request.put('https://api-gateway.sqwdwed123.com/eretw/update-chart')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.query({ auth_id: localStorage.auth_id})
.query({ time_stamp:this.props.time_stamp})
.query({ test_json:JSON.stringify(newadd)})
```

should i pass this test_json through body?

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Any specific reason behind sending the test_json as query param ?

Comment: The test_json seems more like a Request Body than as Query Param

Comment: @piy26 i have update the code

Answer (score 0):

This is usually related to requesting a URL that doesn't exist. Please make sure you're using the correct HTTP method and resource path to a valid resource (the sample invoke URL does not include any resource path). If this still doesn't work. Make sure you actually deployed your API.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Response of Bad Request is because you have the Query Parameter that are not URL Encoded. There are 2 things that you can do now:

1. Pass the test_json as Query Param but making sure that they are URL Encoded. This will put a restriction on the size of the string and hence Not Recommended.
2. Pass the test_json as Request Body. (Recommended)

Comment: I have not worked with ruby anytime but a general understanding of the code `.query({ test_json:JSON.stringify(newadd)})` makes me believe that you are trying to pass the JSON as HTTP Query Param. Please try to pass the JSON via HTTP Body